# Using pandas library for Python, is this how to select specific values from specific rows where columns are a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas data frame that, among other things, has the ages and genders of a couple thousand people (because I do). I have to come up with the average age of the male population in the data frame. I *think* that I have the right code for selecting only the ages of the rows where the 'sex' column = 'Male,' but I wanted to check with the hivemind of programmers. I currently have it so that it selects the age of these rows by doing df.loc at the location where sex = Male, and then putting ['age'] after all of that, but I'm not exactly sure that even works...
Code:

`average_age_men = round(df.loc[(df['sex'] == 'Male')]['age'].mean())`

Answer (score 2):

yes the code would do what you want but its not necessary the most pandonic way of doing it. If instead you used

```
df.groupby('sex')['age'].mean().round()
```

you would get a Dataframe containing the mean ages for all the sexes.

Comment: I tried that after I read your answer and it worked for some time before something went wrong and it was because the thing I got from that is not a dataframe and instead... a "groupby group".

Comment: Hmmm, that should be the result of the first operation `df.groupby('sex')['age']` The `.mean()` transforms it again into a Dataframe. Did you delete that part?